# preventing twice run inside android's textwatcher

Tags: java, android, textwatcher

im working with android's TextWatcher for doing this: when user type, save what typed and after saving, change characters inside Edittext. for example, i have a constant text like"hi im happy" , and every thing i type in edittext user sees that this text is writing(this string shows Tandemly while user typing)! but main text that user types, stored in a variable . i use this code inside afterTextChanged:

```
if(s.toString().charAt(s.length()-1) != 'a'){
    //save inside freaktext variable(append)
    freaktext=freaktext+s.toString().charAt(s.length()-1);

        //change edittext value(what user see's)
    txtfreak.setText(s.toString().substring(0, s.length()-1) + "a"); 
    txtfreak.setSelection(txtfreak.getText().length());
}else{
    freaktext=freaktext+"a";
}
```

i this code i say, if typed character is not "a", save it on a variable named "freaktext" and then change edittext value and put "a" character to the end of string inside edittext. but if user types "a" just save it in freaktext.

bu my problem is: when user types a none "a" character, everything works fine and my code save typed character and then modify edittext value, but when edittext value changes whole code runs again and because last time i change it and put an "a" to it, my code's second part (else) runs and again save an "a" to the end of saved string. in fact when i type "q" i see "qa" in my saved string!! i want that just user directly type "a" in the keyboard, "a" saved and in other situations not. i fact my else section only runs when user directly pressed on "a" key on the keyboard.how i can do this? please help me, this code waste my time for 1 day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside your function, somewhere:

```
boolean weChangedIt = false;
```

Inside `afterTextChanged`:

```
if (weChangedIt) {
     weChangedIt = false;
} else {
    if(s.toString().charAt(s.length()-1) != 'a'){
        weChangedIt = true;
        freaktext=freaktext+s.toString().charAt(s.length()-1);
        txtfreak.setText(s.toString().substring(0, s.length()-1) + "a"); 
        txtfreak.setSelection(txtfreak.getText().length());
    }else{
        freaktext=freaktext+"a";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow!! thank you. i tried several time this method but every time i had a problem and never my code was beautiful and well formatted. but your code works fine and i want to thank you my friend! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
txtfreak.removeTextChangedListener(whateveryourlistenername);
if(s.toString().charAt(s.length()-1) != 'a'){
freaktext=freaktext+s.toString().charAt(s.length()-1);
txtfreak.setText(s.toString().substring(0, s.length()-1) + "a"); 
txtfreak.setSelection(txtfreak.getText().length());

}else{
freaktext=freaktext+"a";
}
txtfreak.addTextChangedListener(whateveryourlistenername);
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Also, you could just use `this` instead of `whateveryourlistenername`.

Comment: I did not know what he has for his listener, he could have a class extend TextWatcher

Comment: Unless he forwarded the `Editable` to another function, it would work regardless of whether his class `implemented` TextWatcher or if it was an anonymous inner class.

Comment: No he could have public class MyTextWatcher extends TextWhatcher and then MyTextWatcher mTextWatcher = new MyTextWatcher() and then addTextChangeListener(mTextWatcher)

Comment: That would still work thanks to inheritance/polymorphism. Try it.